# Boolean in nested schema causing required state

Tags: meteor, schema, meteor-autoform

I have [schemas](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) set up so that I can have an array of complex input sets via [autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform). Something like:

```
address = {
  street:{
    type: String
  },
  city: {
    type: String
  },
  active_address: {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: true
  },
  ...
}

people: {
  name:{
    type: String
  },

  address:{
    type: [address],
    optional: true,
    defaultValue: []
  }
}
```

This way adding an address is optional, but if you add an address all of the address fields are required.

Trying to submit the form throws a required error for every field under "address" except for the `Boolean`, even though the checkbox is not checked.

For reference, I'm creating the form as such:

```
{{#autoForm collection="people" id=formId type="insert" doc=getDocument autosave=true template="autoupdate"}}    
  {{> afQuickField name='name' template="autoupdate" placeholder="schemaLabel"}}
  {{> afQuickField name='address' template="autoupdate"}}
  ...
{{/autoForm}}
```

I'm using custom form templates very heavily based on `bootstrap3` form templates that come with autoform.

**Tried**

Tried adding a hook like so:

```
 formToDoc:function(doc, ss, formId){
    for (var i = 0, l = doc.address.length; i < l; ++i){
      if (!doc.address[i].active_address){
        delete doc.address[i].active_address;
      };
    }
    return doc;
  }
```

Which solves the submit problem, but still inserts an array full of empty strings `""` for the other values. This causes the update form to go haywire, similar as to what's illustrated in my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017347/autoform-5-0-2-nested-schema-inputs-required-on-update).

The issue is that the array isn't empty, but instead has an object of empty values. I could probably run over every value in the form and remove all the fields but that feels very hacky and expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrect in my last assessment. I had removed the `defaultValue: []` from the address field in the person schema. Using that with the following code in the `formToDoc` hook fixes the issue:

```
for (var i = 0, l = doc.address.length; i < l; ++i){
  if (!doc.address[i].active_address){
    doc.address[i].active_address = null;
  }        
}
return doc;
```